# Can't make a clip in FinalCutPro X longer

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro

I am pretty new to FinalCutPro X and want to make my timelapse video with it. So far so good... I am almost finished...
But in the end, I'd like to make it a bit longer.

What I have are a couple of compound clips for each part of my video and then in the end I made one more compound clip with all of the parts to be able to easily adjust the length of the whole video to the music I am using.

Now I wanted to add some more images to my last segment but then I can't drag the clip longer. It will show a red border at the end and wont make it longer. Also, the part on the right is kind of grayed out.

Hard for me to explain the problem, so I made some screenshots.
First one shows the one big compound clip
[image]

Second shows the inner ones (each represents one week)
[image]

And inside those are individual images. Even when I add a couple of more images to the last compound clip, I am not able to make it longer...

[image]

Any idea of what I am doing wrong would help me a lot!!!

And... just a very quick question (don't want to create a whole question for it)... When I slowmo a clip it will show this drag-handle-bar on top to adjust the speed. When I close the project and reopen it again, they are gone... Is there a quick way on how to get them back?

Cheers,
Georg

Answer (score 1):

The red line is shown when there is no more source media left. You've dragged the end of the clip all the way to the end of the source file, so there's no more media to be added. Imagine a video 5 seconds long, of which you've added the first 4 seconds to the timeline, then you try to drag the end of the clip in the timeline beyond 5 seconds — you can't, because there's no more source media in the clip.

The end of the timeline when viewing your compound clip is greyed out because this section is beyond the end of the compound clip range in the containing timeline. The main timeline which contains the compound clip is only showing a portion of the compound clip, and the video in the compound clip beyond the greyed out area will not be played. To play this section, drag the end of the compound clip in the main timeline until the red line is shown.

To quickly show/hide the retime editor for any selected clips, press cmd-R.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!! I updated my question to also show the inside of the second compound clip. You can see in there, that I have images inside that compound clip that are more than the grayed out area shows. So I'd expect that I should be able to make the compound clip longer. And once that is longer, I'd expect to make the outer one also longer?!? But it's not working...